# Android SIP native stack call audio volume

Tags: android, audio, sip

I'm working on a push to talk (walkie talkie) application for Android using the [native sip stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html).
I need to make a button that switches off the audio of the call, but doesn't mute it.

I tried using the AudioManager class to mute the `AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL` stream but without success.

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().
                                        getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, muted);
```

Any suggestions? I'm not sure what else to try. The SIP api doesn't have any methods that can mute the audio output.

Comment: @Tim No, not really. I only managed to lower the volume but I couldn't  mute it. Eventually we took another approach and ended the call entirely instead of setting the volume to 0.

Comment: Hi maydonose, Im having too.. Did you find soluiton? Actually I cant register my sip server, I m using official sipdemo for android and Never I cant registering my sip server. How did you solve it this problem? Did you register your sip server?